# Angular $httpProvider Interceptor and $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, resources, interceptor

I have a simple Interceptor in angular that intercepts requests and adds a authorization header. It also intercepts a response error of 401 to know if the request failed because of authorization.

Unfortunately it seems to mess with $resource, because my $resource calls ALWAYS return the success callback and never an error (be it 400 or 500 whatever).

It's definitly the interceptor, because if I remove it, the $resource calls return with the correct callback.

Any ideas on how to fix this behavior?

Here's the interceptors request:

```
  function request(config) {
    var token = 'whatever-my-token-is';

    if (token) {
      config.headers.authorization = token;
    }

    return config;
  }
```

And the responseError:

```
function responseError(response) {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
  }

  return response;
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a promise to return the error.
adding `$q` to your Interceptor factory.
like so

```
$provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q){
   ...
})
```

and then have the responseError()

```
function responseError(response) {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
  }

 return $q.reject(response);
}
```

this link might help also https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/